# Updated data shows after force refresh (Yii2)

Tags: php, firefox, yii2, ubuntu-18.04

i am working on yii2 basic and when i update a form, data update in db successfully but update   data dnt show in form even after refresh link but when i hard refresh or remove cache then it shows updated data in form , what could  be a possible issue ? , because it was working fine few days before but suddenly it starts showing this behavior even an other application is in same server that is working fine , i need help .
is it yii2 configuration issue or server configuration issue?
in db.php i have these two values

```
'enableSchemaCache' => true,
'enableQueryCache' => false,
```

i tried enable schema cache to false but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any other caching like page caching or fragment caching?

Comment: @masoudvatandoost code is on svn that is problem may be someone update a caching fragment etc , i tried but can't find any clue

Comment: try to find problem with var_dump and die  or use Yii2 logger on each step. The cache maybe on your model or in your view or even in a behavior in your controller. use Yii::info() with specific category and then check them on your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's some sort of (data) caching enabled.
You can :

1. Check the methods you use to retrieve data from the database to see if caching has been enabled .
   Such methods are : `find()` , `findOne()` , `findAll()` .
   Check if they have been overridden or extended by your code.

If the default `find()` method or any of its variants have been extended, then you could also extend the `afterSave()` method to flush the cache after performing updates to the database.
Here's what I use in my test environment to flush the cache after performing an update .

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

    //Clears cache if this is an update
    if( !$insert)
    {
        if(method_exists ($this, 'flushCache'))
        {
            $this->flushCache();
        }
    }
}

public function flushCache()
{
    Yii::$app->cache->delete($this->getCacheKey());
}

protected function getCacheKey()
{
    return self::getCacheKeyPrefix().   $this->getPrimaryKey() ;
}
public static function getCacheKeyPrefix()
{
    return self::CACHE_PREFIX   .  self::getTableSchema()->name;
}
```

Explanation

1. After writing to the DB, the afterSave() event is called by Yii.
2. If an insert was carried out, then cache flushing is skipped. If an UPDATE was performed, then  the flushCache method is called to clear the cache.

Note that you should understand how caching has been set up in your own environment and then amend flush the cache as appropriate to suit your needs.

Let me know how it goes.
Thanks and HTH.